# Restrict access to a S3 bucket to admin users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a bucket that can be specifically accessed by a user with a particular policy attached to it. Admin users, for example, with managed policies such as AdministratorAccess can of course access all resources and I would like to avoid that. Is the recommended approach that of locking down access via roles?

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 buckets are private by default.

If you do not wish to grant certain users access to the bucket, then simply **do not grant them access**.

If you are granting wildcard access to some users (eg Admins), you can **add a Bucket Policy** with `Deny` actions that prohibits access to the bucket for all but selected users (via a `NotCondition`). A `Deny` will always override an `Allow`.

However, you will need to code the policies carefully, since Admin users might have permission to modify such policies.

In situations where there is very sensitive information (eg HR data), some companies **create a separate AWS Account** where only specific users have access and **Admin users do not have access**. This takes more work, but is likely necessary for sensitive data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, appreciated. I have my policy at the user level, rather than having a bucket policy. Can I modify the user-attached policy or is it best practice to actually having the additional restriction at the BucketPolicy level?

Comment: Permissions for specific users should always be granted as a policy on the IAM User or Group. Public permissions will be in the Bucket Policy. An exception is like the above, where you grant "too much" permission at the user level and then add `Deny` restrictions within the Bucket Policy.